# Parallelize upwind scheme in Matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parfor

**Statement**

Suppose we consider a simple upwind scheme in Matlab

```
for k = 1:kFin % time-loop
    % space-loop
    un(2:nx) = u(2:nx) - cfl*(u(2:nx) - u(1:nx-1)); 
    % BC
    un(1) = un(nx);
    % update
    u = un; 
end
```

**Problem**

How to parallelize it via **parfor** or **spmd** or else?

Comment: Think about what the scheme is doing - each time step *relies* on the previous step. That loop is stepping through time, you can't take time in some random order, by their very nature iterative methods are linearly computed. Your comments are also slightly misleading - you're not looping in space, you're just approximating the spatial derivative term at that point in time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the goal of the question (parallelization) contradicts the nature of the problem (iterative methods) - the maths doesn't work.

Comment: @Wolfie Thank you for your kindness comments. My knowledge is very weak in sence of implementation of parallel algorithms for sure. For the other hand, one may state the naive question above, i.e. how to parallelize the upwind. Anyway, thank's for the comments again.

Comment: Sorry if I was a bit blunt, but do you get my gist? Parallel operations don't run in sequence, so have to be treated as completely independent

Comment: @Wolfie All izz well indeed. I can imagine that parallel operations work something different for sure. The thing is that I'm curious to undertand how a recurrence algorithm, computation of Fibonnacci sequence for instance, could be perfrormed in a parallel style.